# Which is the strongest base?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base

When I was in lower grades, I was taught $\ce{NaOH and KOH}$ are the strongest bases. But I realised later that there can be more stronger ones. After a bit of research on the internet, I found these three to be spoken more about.

1. Lithium diisopropylamide (LDA)
2. Methyllithium (MeLi)
3. Butyllithium (BuLi)

Wikipedia on LDA says that the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of its conjugate acid is $36$, which means the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}$ value at $\pu{298K}$ is $-22$. (Since $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b} = 14$).
Likewise, for BuLi and MeLi I found the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b}$ value to be $-36$ and $-34$ respectively from the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values of their conjugate acids. So, can we conclude that BuLi is the strongest base? Is this absolute basic strength defined?

---

**Sources for $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values:**

- [Wikipedia-LDA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_diisopropylamide)
- [pKa of MeLi and BuLi](http://www.uwindsor.ca/people/jgreen/sites/uwindsor.ca.people.jgreen/files/pka_bases.pdf)

Comment: Depends on the solvent system to some extent

Comment: pKb as measure of basic strength takes into account the solvent and the proton afinity of the species. pKb is effectively a free energy of reaction. So it takes into account the whole system: what the species is, what conentration, temperature, the solvent. Proton affinity by itself is a measure of the energy associated with being a base -- i.e. extracting protons, it's somewhat more universal. But then again the environment of a species effects it ability to extract those protons so if you wanted to make a basic *solution* you'd need to take into account the pKb too.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like it's neither of the three; ortho-diethynylbenzene dianion has the highest calculated proton affinity.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ortho-diethynylbenzene_dianion)

> [image]

according to calculations, ortho-diethynylbenzene dianion is the strongest base, with a proton affinity of $\pu{1843 kJ \cdot mol^{−1}}$.

This base claimed the title of the strongest base 2016 *ish*, another base may have grabbed the spot but I haven't been able to find it.

B L J Poad et al, Chem. Sci., 2016, DOI: [10.1039/c6sc01726f](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2016/sc/c6sc01726f#!divAbstract)

Comment: Any mention on the pKb value? Also I asked another question reg. the absolute basic strength.

Comment: Ofc no absolute basic strength is not defined . No idea regarding the pKb values

Comment: Oh! Why is it not defined when we can say a single base is the strongest as of now? And is proton affinity the only factor?

Comment: @Molly the doi link I provided deals with all that

Comment: Seems a little unfair to bring in di-anions, but whatever.

Comment: How can you get the di-anion to start with?  Neutral compounds or even mono-anions are more accessible.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Ah! Alright. Was thinking about the same.  Do you find any of that kind stronger than what I have mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: @AvnishKabaj I read the link twice/thrice. But I couldn’t find an explanation for “why proton affinity is the decisive factor?” when it comes to base strength. Thoughts?

Comment: @Molly More energy released = more stable the protonated product

Comment: @AvnishKabaj was asking more like “ Why in comparison to pKb”? I get the stability of the di-anion will obvi be more when it gets protonated.

Comment: I have added my queries into the question. Sorry if I’m asking too many questions. Thanks!